# entityfieldquery execution error

Tags: database

I'm learning entityfieldquery api

I wrote a simple module

```
function demo_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['demo'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'demo_list',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function demo_list() {
  $query=  new EntityFieldQuery();

  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type ', 'node')
    ->execute();

  print_r($result);
}
```

I got this error

```
EntityFieldQueryException: For this query an entity type must be specified. in EntityFieldQuery->propertyQuery() (line 1195 of C:\openserver\domains\drupal7.localhost\includes\entity.inc).
```

I read many articles. This is the most simplest query but it is not working.

Comment: I am closing this question as the error is a typo in the condition used; "entity_type " is not a condition the `EntityFieldQuery` class understands. Questions where the error is a typo are too localized questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just got the error. remove space from "entity_type "  
from this line 
`$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type ', 'node') ->execute();`